# C++ Passing a member function of a template class to another function

Tags: c++, templates, functor, member-functions, typename

This works fine for a non-member function. How can I change it to be able to perform the same operation with a member function. I have tried the "function pointers" technique, and it was not efficient in terms of performance.

```
template <typename Func>
int f(int a, Func somefunc) {
  somefunc(a);
  return 0;
}
...
f(5,myfoo);
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
int myClass::mybar() {    
  f(5,myfoo); //where myfoo is actually "myClass::myfoo" here. 
              //I want myClass to be the template class. 
}
```

How can I define a template class and make its member-function template as well, such that `f` works with any class and any member-function?

Thanks!

Comment: What is this "function pointers" technique you speak of?

Comment: have you tried to overload your function with another template parameter for the class ? Then the function's type will be Class::Func

Comment: @BrianBi I mean function pointer in c++! like passing the address of the function

Comment: @Geoffroy: If you mean template <typename Class, typename Func>, I have tried it. and then instead of Func, I have used Class::Func. did not work!

Comment: What is `myfoo` - a member function of a class template, a member template of a plain class, ...?

Comment: @aschepler: yes, it is a member function of a class template.

Comment: A static member or non-static member?  If it's a non-static member, where will `f` get the `myClass` object required to call `myfoo`?

Comment: @Bian Bi Are you saying that function pointers is not a technique? I can tell you multiple techniques to not use function pointers that may not be as efficient.

Comment: @Claudiordgz function pointers are a core part of the language and their use is straightforward. It seems strange to me to call it a "technique", that's all.

Comment: @Brian Bi For me function pointers are a brush of certain caliber, and there are tons of brushes to work with. You can create a masterpiece with a huge paintbrush, but some parts will be harder where it requires another... more delicate type of brush.

Comment: @aschepler, you are so right! I cannot make them static. They call other non-static members. So, there is no way to do it?

Comment: In C++ using function pointers is rarely reasonable, they are usually used as a bridge between C++ and C libraries and sometimes as "optimization". C++ has more sophisticated tools than function pointers.

Comment: There is probably a way to do it, but I still don't understand what "it" is.

Comment: Why would you use function pointers for this case in specific... It seems like a case foooor.... tu turun tuuuu... Policies!!!

Comment: @aschepler: to pass a non-static member function to a plain function as a parameter.

Comment: @pasztorpisti, I am not saying they are not efficient at all. In my case, they given me degraded performance, because of using lots of loops

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism First you should write nice good looking code, then optimize/uglify where necessary. Most codebases contain very few performance critical spots/loops compared to the rest of the code that is not performance critical at all an in these places nice easy-to-understand design should dominate. In my opinion member pointers suck. Often member pointer based solution can be replaced with something simpler/nicer.

Comment: Function pointers degrade performance? lolwut? Then what's your code inside this functions?

Comment: I have used them already. In a multithreaded environment, they are really bad! The code inside is a nested loop over somefunc

Comment: Maybe http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/functionoids2.html , or some other part of C++ FAQ section 33, is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Wait... Hammer Time

You mean do something like this??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void my_int_func(int x)
{
    printf( "%d\n", x );
}

void my_string_func(std::string x)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

template <typename type, typename Func>
int f(type a, Func somefunc) {
  somefunc(a);
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
    void (*foo)(int);
    void (*bar)(std::string);
    /* the ampersand is actually optional */
    foo = &my_int_func;
    bar = &my_string_func;

    f(5, foo);
    f(std::string("thing"), bar);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is again function pointer. right? I have tried this. No good performance when called so many times.

Comment: Performance? They're more of a tool for saving code, not really for improving performance.

Comment: That is exactly what  I am concerned about. Having an implementation that does not degrade the performance. Anyway, thanks for the code!

Comment: I'm just gonna leave this right here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design

Comment: BTW... usually more code quantityt means better performance (that's why compilers unroll loops)... but it also means harder to read code. Watch out for performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now comes the said truth: Member pointers are also pointers (OK, sometimes they are just offsets, and it can be even more compliated in case of multiple/virtual inheritance...). And now maybe a possible solution although I don't know what is your actual use case for passing a member function pointer to a template method of a template...

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    C()
    {
        f(5, &C::f);
    }

    template <typename Func>
    int f(int a, Func somefunc)
    {
        (this->*somefunc)(a);
        return 0;
    }
    void f(int i)
    {
        printf("%s(%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, i);
    }
    void g(int i)
    {
        printf("%s(%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, i);
    }
};

int main()
{
    C<int> c;
    c.f(6, &C<int>::g);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I want f to be an API. so it is not aware of the class or its member functions implementations.

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism in that case you have to pass an instance pointer too to `f()` along with the member pointer because a member pointer is useless without an instance pointer. An instance pointer + method pointer together is basically a delegate (delegate == pointer to a method of an actual instance) that is unfortunately unsupported by C++ however in C++11 you have several options to achieve your goal depending on what you actually want to do.

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism My previous statement about delegates isn't totally correct, a delegate isn't necessarily an instance pointer + method. A delegate is simply a callable object, it is like a function but its actual implementation can actually be backed by a normal function or optionally a method with a bound instance pointer / this pointer parameter.

Comment: Are you sure it is not possible in C++?

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism C++ doesn't natively support delegates but you can simulate them nicely with C++11 features. The question is: What do you want to achieve? Maybe all you need is lambda/std::function, maybe some variadic template magic. The goal is to provide an easy to use API that results in nice code when someone writes code on top of your API.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I need a lambda-like function, but in C++. The only limitation is to be able to point to member classes. Maybe I have to think about it more. Thanks for your support. I will come back to this  very soon!